# how to make a url decide what`s in a <input>

Tags: html, url

I was wondering if it was possible to get a http://yoursite.com/index.php?page=order&ordernumber=1 and then the ordernumber (=1) will get injected into the    input type="text" name="ordernumber"

I hope someone knows an answer to this i am struggling with this

Comment: Step 1: Pick a programming language.

Comment: Step 2: implement it.

Comment: Step 3: show it to us and explain at which point you struggle.

Comment: "*I hope someone knows an answer…I am struggling with this*" - 'struggling' implies 'attempting,' you'll get a far better reaction, in future, if you show us your best (broken) attempts and explain why they don't work, where they go wrong, what they do that they shouldn't or what they don't do that they should. Any question that can, it seems, be answered with a simple Boolean 'no' or, in this case, 'yes,' don't typically go over well, here on [SO].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have PHP, then you can use jQuery also.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="ordernumber" id="ordernumber" value="" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function() {
    var orderNumber = getUrlParameter('ordernumber');
    if (typeof orderNumber !== 'undefined') {
        //console.log(orderNumber);
        $('#ordernumber').val(orderNumber);
    }

});

function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<input type="text" name="ordernumber" value="<?php echo $_GET['ordernumber']?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

For a vanilla javascript solution, you can use something like this.

```
<input type="text" id="ordernumber" name="ordernumber" value="">
<script>
  var matches = document.URL.match(/ordernumber=([0-9]+)/);
  var ordernumber = matches[1];
  document.getElementById('ordernumber').value = ordernumber;
</script>
```

For a jQuery solution, see [lolka_bolka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087195/lolka-bolka)'s answer.

For a PHP solution, see [Stark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4140161/stark)'s answer.